Align images from carousel in React with outer components
I am using the library react-multi-carousel, however, I am having difficulties aligning the images so the left border from the first image aligns with the items in the outside, in this case an h2, like so:

And the right border from the last image aligns with the outer element, which in this case, is the "shop" button, like so:

This is the link to the CodeSanbox. Is this possible to do with that library?

This may help
.react-multi-carousel-track {
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.react-multiple-carousel__arrow {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}


Yes, this looks so much better. Thanks a bunch.
